# angularjs radio button not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, radio-button

I have a radio button inside `ng-repeat` functionality. So, it will create radio button  on each step. But for some step radio button is getting checked and for some radio button is not getting checked even if we have data from backend.

Issue: For some steps radio button is not getting checked even if it has ng-modal value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<div class="temp">
 <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" ng-model="info.Unit" value="1"  name="optradio-00">unit1</label>
 <label class="radio"><input type="radio"  ng-model="info.Unit" value="0"  name="optradio-00"> unit2</label>
</div>  
<div class="temp">
 <label class="radio"><input type="radio"  ng-model="info.Unit" value="1"  name="optradio-01">unit1</label>
 <label class="radio"><input type="radio"  ng-model="info.Unit" value="0"  name="optradio-01">unit2</label>
</div>  

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[radio image with value printed on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G8ek.png)

Comment: It's because you are using same 'ng-model' which has duplicated 'value'.

Comment: If you want to separate them, each radio must has a different 'ng-model' name, and make 'info.Unit' using those 'ng-model's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below concept to fire the event on `ng-change`

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="radiobutton1" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="radiobutton2" ng-change='newValue(value)'>
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="radiobutton3" ng-change='newValue(value)'>    
<hr> 
</div>
```

write the code in app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value= 'radiobutton1';

    $scope.newValue = function(value) {
       console.log(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to get this value {{i.Unit}} from backend, but radio button is not getting checked

Comment: please see the image attached for more clarity

Comment: Pls share the Demo example on jsfiddle/plnkr with dummy data so that i can help you easily..

Comment: Hi santosh, I have edited the issue which is reproducible. I need to have same ng-modal variable for which i am receiving value from backend. Pls check..

Comment: Why for example is this working perfectly but it doesn’t when the type=‘radio’ ??? <input type='checkbox' ng-init='checkStatus=false' ng-model='checkStatus' ng-click='doIfChecked(checkStatus)'>